# Did Ahsoka know Padme was pregnant?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, ahsoka-tano

Basically what the title says.

It's unclear throughout TCW if Ahsoka ever knew about Anakin and Padme.  It's very likely that, since Anakin had told Rex about Padme in season 7, Anakin was going to tell Ahsoka but was never able to.  Since she's so young throughout TCW, it's never clear if she picks up on Anakin and Padme's relationship.

Ahsoka never interacts with Padme in season 7.  But at Padme's funeral, her body was made to still appear pregnant.  So - did Ahsoka ever know that Padme was pregnant?  If she did, she'd probably have a guess as to the father.

Comment: she seems to have picked up on something given that during her exit in Season 5 she hints that she at least knows something is up w/ Anakin when he talks about having wanted to leave the Jedi Order also sometimes and she says "I know"

Comment: Ahsoka wasn't at the funeral and Padmé had mostly been keeping on the downlow for a few months before she died. Unless Ahsoka saw some video footage, it's possible that she just never found out.

Comment: The insane Dark Empire in utero theory: Ashoka didn’t necessarily need to be at the funeral. She just needed to be around Padme during Padme’s pregnancy and prospective Luke or Leia fetuses could’ve reached out to her, or Ashoka could’ve sensed something in Force she could then put 2+2 together.

Comment: Before or after she heard of Luke Skywalker?

Answer (score 1):

Ahsoka absolutely knew Anakin and Padme were in a relationship, based on her comments to Padme during the Forces of Destiny short "Unexpected Company", when she showed up on a "mission" that Padme and Anakin were supposedly going on which was really them getting away for some private time.

It isn't, however, known if Ahsoka knew they were married, or that Padme was pregnant.

Comment: You might want to clarify whether Ahsoka did or didn’t know about Padme’s pregnancy as your final sentence seems to contradict the rest of your answer

Answer (score -1):

My theory,

The only way Obi-Wan Kenobi I believe knew that Padme was Pregnant was not due to his Proficiency in the Force, It was due to his Proficiency in feelings i.e You could sit next to Obi-Wan Kenobi crying and he would say "Sorry about your Father" and that comes with age and experience in feelings. Although Asoka was proficient in the Force she needed plenty of years still to be proficient with feelings to read anyone just like that.

Remember Yoda with Luke's Skywalker's training?

You must feel the Force around you; here, between you, me, the tree, the rock, everywhere, yes. Even between the land and the ship.

FEELINGS. So middle age Obi-Wan Kenobi must have felt it due to Padme's emotions without even touching her. Asoka was a bit young for that expertise.

My Theory

Comment: So is the answer to the question, if Ahsoka knew Padmé was pregnant, is no?  First, you should be clear and start with that.  Second, there are other possible ways she might learn that don't rely purely on the Force; can you discount those as well?  Finally, do you have any evidence to support your theory?

Comment: @DavidW 1) I believe so yes Asoka wasn't aware. 2) No I dont discount other ways she could have found out with all the Technology around as an example. 3) I dont have hard evidence, but at the same time I didn't see any evidence in TCW that Asoka knew anything hence the theory as to how Obi-Wan Kenobi knew there was a link with Anakin and Padmé.